# Checking for what .po files are available

Tags: c#, internationalization, monodevelop, translation, gettext

I'm writing an application that I would like to offer the user the ability to change the language on the fly.  I'd like the application to be able to only offer switching the language to choices that are available on the system.  As I understand it, I would need to check for which ".po" files are installed.

I'm using Monodevelop/Mono, and the Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("blah blah") style for all translatable items.  Within the Monodevelop directories I can find the ".po" files I have supplied, but this would not necessarily relate to an installed system that could be on Windows, Unix or Mac.

It appears Mono.Unix.Catalog does not offer a method for this, so I suspected I'd need to perhaps use Environment.CurrentDirectory or perhaps Environment.SystemDirectory to try to find the locations where the .po would be, but it seems there are too many variable that would affect this:

- Is it Win, Mac or Unix?
- If it is Unix, is it Ubuntu, SUSE, Vine, etc?
- If not on the system, is it on the User folder?
- If it is a user folder, would that location be different on Win, Mac
  and various Unix variants?

Is there a simple way to determine which ".po"s are available on the system?

Comment: Could you try to section your text with paragraphs? A wall of text doesn't invite people to read.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it a big prettier now.  I did have returns, but didn't realize that it smashed things together.  My bad.